# Simulate many datasets in tidyr

Tags: r, simulation, tidyr, tibble

I want to end up with a tidy data structure like the one below:

```
N    | r     | data     | stat
---------------------------------
10   | 0.2   | <tibble> | 0.5
20   | 0.3   | <tibble> | 0.86
...
```

`data` is generated from the parameters in the first columns and `stat` is computed on `data`. If I have the first two columns, how do I add tibbles of datasets?

As a minimal example, here is a function to create two correlated columns:

```
correlated_data = function(N, r) {
  MASS::mvrnorm(N, mu=c(0, 4), Sigma=matrix(c(1, r, r, 1), ncol=2))
}
```

Running this for all combinations of `N` and `r`, I start by doing

```
# Make parameter combinations
expand.grid(N=c(10,20,30), r=c(0, 0.1, 0.3)) %>%
  group_by(N, r) %>%
  expand(set=1:100) %>%  # create 100 of each combination

  # HERE! How to add a N x 2 tibble to each row?
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(data=correlate_data( N, r))

  # Compute summary stats on each (for illustration only; not tested)
  mutate(   
     stats = map(data, ~cor.test(.x[, 1], .x[, 2])),  # Correlation on each
     tidy_stats = map(stats, tidy))  # using broom package
```

I do have more parameters (N, r, distribution) and I will be computing more summaries. If alternative workflows are better, I welcome that as well.

Comment: where is `dist` defined

Comment: Try `mutate(data=list(correlate_data( N, r)))`

Comment: or `mutate(data= map2(N,r,correlate_data))` and you don't need `rowwise`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it for two variables:

```r
map2(N, r, correlated_data)
```

For more variables, use

```r
pmap(list(N, r), correlated_data)
```

So the full procedure in the original question becomes:

```r
expand.grid(N=c(10, 20, 30), r=c(0, 0.1, 0.3)) %>%
  group_by(N, r) %>%
  expand(set=1:200) %>%  # create 100 of each combination

  # HERE! How to add a N x 2 tibble to each row?
  mutate(
    data = map2(N, r, correlated_data),
    stats = map(data, ~cor.test(.[, 1], .[,2])),
    tidy_stats = map(stats, tidy)
  ) %>%  # using broom package

  unnest(tidy_stats)
```